# Duplex WCF Service call using javascript (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wcf, rest

Now i am working with WCF Rest Service

Now i am trying WCF Duplex Communication in WCF REST Service

Currently i am calling service through jquery AJAX and getting response back to it

Like this:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: varType, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
        url: varUrl, // Location of the service
        data: varData, //Data sent to server
        contentType: varContentType, // content type sent to server
        dataType: varDataType, //Expected data format from server
        processdata: varProcessData, //True or False
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: varCache,
        timeout: 200000,
        success:  function (response) {// When Service call success
                 var names = response.d;
                 alert(names);
             },
        error: function (xhr) {// When Service call fails
          alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

But in duplex communication there is a call back contract in the service which service communicate later to the client.

How can i get the response of the call back contract in jquery ajax ?

## **Also i have one doubt, Is webHttpbinding will support for Duplex communication ?**

Comment: Did I answer your questions?

Answer (score 0):

> How can i get the response of the call back contract in jquery ajax ?

IMHO to receive a call from your service to a client via HTTP SignalR should be used. It uses push technology, long-pulling and other to allow this.  Another way to do this would be to emulate this by repeatedly calling a service for changes.

It seems hard to do it via `WSDualHttpBinding` which supports duplex communication. Please see a note by Juval Lowy in the "Programming WCF" book where he states for this binding: "Duplex callbacks are nonstandard, as there is no industry reference that states how the client endpoint address is passed to the ser­vice or how the service publishes the callback contract in the first place."

> Also i have one doubt, Is webHttpbinding will support for Duplex communication ?

I believe it is not supported there. [WebHttpBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.webhttpbinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not support sessions (`ReliableSession` property) and this is required by the duplex communication (see [System-Provided Bindings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

And BTW WebHttpBinding is superseded by ASP.NET WebApi.

Comment: Your answer may be correct with `WSDualHttpBinding` , but i have to achieve duplex communication using `webHttpBinding`, i have used HATEOAS concept to achieve this.